# Pyinstaller not including pywin32-ctypes in executable

Tags: python-3.x, windows, winapi, pyinstaller, pywin32

Used the following command for compiling:

`pyinstaller --clean --hidden-import pywin32-ctypes --hidden-import pywin32 --hidden-import pypiwin32 --onefile --debug=all --noupx MRTFiles/attack_controller.py`

Note, that the `--hidden-import`´s are already tries to fix the issue. Also I am using the current development version (4.0.dev0+a1f92c6a08) of pyinstaller from within a clean venv with python 3.7.6 installed.

Compile-log:
https://gist.github.com/chwba/9a81592f4ea62dfdff4bcb496c626f01

When running the executable log:
https://gist.github.com/chwba/baa100ec7a0c399b79344d021ca803a6

The relevant lines in the executable run log seem to be:

```
import 'win32ctypes.core' # <pyimod03_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x000001D96668D108>
# win32ctypes.core._common not found in PYZ
# win32ctypes.core.cffi not found in PYZ
# destroy win32ctypes.pywin32.win32api
# destroy win32ctypes.pywin32
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

Also check https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4212 and https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3793

I have tried all suggested fixes there without any success.